# How to get config values inside the triggered method in azure webjob 3.x sdk

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a continuously running webjob that uses queue trigger. I need some data that is configured in the app.config file and i use

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%queueName%")] Model modelMessage, int dequeueCount, [Blob("%blobStorageName%")] CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer, string id)
{
// some code here
var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting"];
// some code using setting
}
```

to get the data into setting into the variable. But all of this is in Azure webjobs 2.1 sdk.
But from 3.x we only have appsettings.json file. how do i get the setting from json file into inside the trigger method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used dependency injection to inject HostBuilderContext to the constructor and got the config from there.